# What's the deal with Rails' alter_table method?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, alter-table

I've been using sqlite3 for my database under development and my app has gotten complex enough that it's a bit slow to work with.

I've just switched to MySQL and run `rake db:create ; rake db:migrate` and one of my migrations failed with the following error message:

```
undefined method `alter_table` for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter:0xb6e6088c>
```

I've had a quick google and turned up nothing. Then I checked the API and there is no documented method `alter_table`. However, it does work with sqlite3!

Here's my migration:

```
class AddSettingsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    alter_table :users do |t|
      t.text signature
      ...
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

This works as expected with sqlite3.

Am I going crazy? Did I just invent this method and it happened to be an undocumented feature that works only on a subset of supported databases?

Does anyone have some insight on this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the others mentioned, this is probably a method used only for sqlite.
The documention mentions change_table, so use that one instead, it should work the same way:

```
class AddSettingsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.text :signature
      ...
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be unique just to sqlite

```
yvaine:activerecord-2.3.5 root# find . -type f -exec grep -l alter_table {} \;
```

./lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb

It'll probably be safer just to use the change_column method instead, as that abstracts the alter table method.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cdf60e46cc01e5f7b14e95a0b7d914516fcdcbc1/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb) shows there's an `alter_table` protected method in the Sqlite adapter.

Comment: Hmm. Why can I call this directly? Is this an oversight that I should submit a bug report for?

Answer (score 0):

I had different handlers for java adapter to sqlite regarding regular expresion manipulation.
Maybe rails does not completly rule over adaptor.